# "Boost filesystem create_directory() throws illegal byte sequence error even with correct file path encoding"

Tags: c++, boost, encoding

C++プログラムでディレクトリを作成するためにboost::filesystemライブラリを使用しようとしています。以下が実際のコードです：

```
boost::filesystem::path dir(path);
if (!boost::filesystem::exists(dir)) {
    boost::filesystem::create_directory(dir);
}
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
boost::filesystem::create_directory: Illegal byte sequence [system:92]: "@��l"
```

このエラーの原因がよくわかりません。使っているパスが正しいことは確認しました、M1 Macでプログラムを実行しています。何が問題で、どうすれば解決できるのでしょうか？

パスを短いものに変えてみましたがダメで、boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()でパスを変換してみましたが、こちらもダメでした。またboostへのリンクも確認しました

Comment: 作成しようとしているディレクトリ名は何ですか？ ASCIIなら作れますか？

Comment: @sayuri 作成しようとしているディレクトリ名は"./results"です．
デバッグしたところ，boost::filesystem::pathの中で，_M_p:"./results"ですが，_M_local_bufの中身が文字化けしておりました．

Comment: C++17 では標準規格に正式採用されて `std::filesystem` に移っていますので 2023 年である今においては（処理系次第ですが） `boost::filesystem` でなくて `std::filesystem` を使ってみるとよいかも。あともし本当に文字化け系なら `<clocale>` して `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` してみるのもテストとしてよいかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

「boost::filesystem::exists」も同じ理由で失敗するに違いない。

ここで「boost::filesystem::create_directory」が「mkdir()」を呼び出していることがわかります:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp

また、「boost::filesystem::path」は「char」サイズの魔法です:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/boost/filesystem/path.hpp

次のコードを試していただけますか?

```
#include <sys/stat.h> // https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/mkdir.html
#include <iostream>

// [...]

boost::filesystem::path dir(path);
if (mkdir(dir.c_str(), S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO)) std::cout << "Fail" << std::endl;
else std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
```

このコードも失敗する場合は、これを試してください:

```
#include <sys/stat.h> // https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/mkdir.html
#include <iostream>

// [...]

if (mkdir("./results", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO)) std::cout << "Fail" << std::endl;
else std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
```

これは解決策ではありません。質問には十分な情報がありません。
これはあなたの分析を助けるためです。

Comment: 最終的に，コンパイラをGCCからclangに変えることで解決しました．
これについてなにかわかることはありますか？

Comment: わかりませんが、GCC で間違った 「#ifdef」 ブランチが取られたのではないかと思います。